# A relation between some matrix determinants is needed

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $$C = \begin{bmatrix} B| (\lambda I- A)^{-1}\cdot B| ... |(\lambda I- A)^{-(n-1)} \cdot B\end{bmatrix} $$ an invertible matrix, and let 
$$ K = \begin{bmatrix}B| A\cdot B| ...|A^{n-1}\cdot B\end{bmatrix}$$ be another invertible matrix. Can anyone find a relation between $det(C)$ and $det(K)$? An equality, inequality, etc. $\lambda \in \mathcal{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the notation I suppose $B$ is a column vector in the above. We have:
$$ (\lambda-A)^{n-1} C = 
\left[ (\lambda-A)^{n-1} B \mid (\lambda-A)^{n-2}B \mid\ ...\  \mid B \right] $$
Now $(\lambda-A)^{n-1}- (-A)^{n-1}$ is a polynomial of degree $n-2$ in $A$ so the first column may be expanded as a linear combination of the remaining colomns. We may therefore replace the first column by $(-A)^{n-1} B$  when taking determinants. By induction this is true for all columns so we are left with:

$$ \det( (\lambda-A)^{n-1} C) = \det \left[ (\lambda-A)^{n-1} B \mid (\lambda-A)^{n-2}B \mid\ ...\  \mid B \right] = \det \left[(-A)^{n-1} B \mid (-A)^{n-2}B \mid\ ...\  \mid B \right] $$
We then get (I believe the signs cancels completely but you've better check): 
$$ p_\lambda(A)^{n-1} \det C = \det(K)$$
with $p_A(\lambda)=\det(\lambda-A)$ being the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Comment: Instead of $(\lambda I - A)^{n-1}\cdot B$ will remain $-A\cdot (\lambda I -A) ^{n-2}\cdot B$ and that can be further reduced with it's column neighbors ... ?!

Comment: So: $K = [B| ... | A^{n-1}B]$, therefore $det(K) = det([B| ...| (\lambda I - A)^{n-1}])$ because  $(\lambda I - A)^{n-1}$ is a linear combination from $I, A, ... , A^{n-1}$, $(\lambda I - A)^{n-2}$ is a linear combination from $I, A, ... , A^{n-2}$ etc. A linear combination is given by the Newton binomial. Right?

Comment: A part from the sign you may argue like this. The matrix which relates the powers of $\lambda-A$ with those of $-A$ is triangular with one on the diagonal. You then get equality of determinants.